# Safest way to turn docker cli bash commands into an api for external application in production use

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm running a program that uses several docker images and containers and it's all spawned and managed by the code. At the same time, I need to enter into the `docker exec -it cli bash` and execute some commands. These commands however cant be manual and must be made into an api. After extensive searching the closest thing I found is `docker remote api` [https://blog.trifork.com/2013/12/24/docker-from-a-distance-the-remote-api]. However, I'm a bit scared messing with the internals of docker. I want the spawning and management to remain controlled by the program. I only need to run a limited number of commands to docker cli. Is docker remote api the right way to go? Will it handle scale- my application may see ~27000 mobile and webapps use/call the apis from different parts of the world. Tried and tested solutions would be preferred.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There’s not an easy answer to this.  Since you include “safest” in the question title, I will suggest you probably need to do some redesign of your application architecture.

The first critical detail is this: **being able to run any Docker command, or access the Docker API, implies unrestricted root access on the host**.  You can trivially `docker run` an image with writeable root-level access to the host’s filesystem and steal public keys, user passwords, give yourself sudo access, and so on.  Using it as a core part of your workflow is incredibly dangerous.  **Turning on the Docker remote API at all is incredibly dangerous.**

As a corollary to this, while `docker exec` is handy as a debugging tool, you can’t really use it as part of your core workflow.  As you note running commands by hand as a trusted administrator doesn’t scale.  There are also dangers in shell quoting: you need to make sure an argument doesn’t look like `foo; docker run -v/:/host ...` and inadvertently gain access to the host system.

In my mind your only real option here is to do this “properly”.  Take whatever administrative commands you need to do and wrap them in some API, probably HTTP-based.  Build a new service (or several) and add it to your Docker deployment.  Maybe under the hood that launches a shell script as a subprocess, but the API wrapper has control over the arguments and can double-check things.  The plus side is that this approach probably won’t be a choke point if your application does need to scale out.